# How to load image outside of Frontend folder

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I have a react project, the structure in the project folder is:

```
- React Project   
  - Frontend  
    - src
    - public
      - data
  - Backend
```

Right now, if I want to load an image, I will put it in the Frontend/public/data folder and write url='data/image.jpg' in frontend source code.
But I want to load images in Backend folder, how can I realize it? THANKS!!

**UPDATE**
There would be lots of images in the Backend folder, I also want to let user upload image in the application and store them in Backend folder. So I can't import them one by one in frontend src code.

Comment: How do you host your project? Do you put font-end and back-end in the same host?

Comment: Hi @Tony Nguyen, no, they're in different hosts, frontend is localhost:3000 and backend is localhost:5000

Comment: `localhost:3000` and `localhost:5000` is just different port, I mean in production do you host them in the same host (same cloud computer...)?

Comment: Yes. But now I just need to implement it on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- React Project   
 - Frontend  
  - src
    - ComponentWithImage.jsx
  - public
    - data
 - Backend
  - images
     flower.png
```

For example you use the image in `ComponentWithImage` you can do like this

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import flower from "../../Backend/images/flower.png"

export default function ComponentWithImage() {

 return (
   <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
 );
}
```

Update: Based on your updated requirements there is a recommended way that.

- When a user upload an image you store them in a cloud storage such as AWS S3, you will get a link of the image from S3 then you store that link in database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this approach works for those who only have fixed few images.    But in my application, there would be lots of images in the Backend folder, so I can't import them one by one in frontend src code.

Comment: Check my updated answer which is based on your new requirement.